# show value of variable when mouse hovers over in Emacs/gdb?

Tags: emacs, gdb, tooltip, elisp, ddd-debugger

I am using GDB with emacs and sometimes use GDB with DDD.

Starting version 22 (???) Emacs provides a tool-bar-mode, where you can do
the most important commands like run, next, step, up/down of stack frames in the emacs UI.
As such , I have moved away from DDD, since anyways I run most commands through command line and the sometime through the limited UI given in the tool-bar-mode.

However, the ability to hover your mouse over a variable and make the value to pop-up still seems to be missing. Does anyone know about some mode in emacs or some .el file that would allow Emacs to do the same. 
This kinda goes against emacs not being a gui-ide. I can still use watchpoints/local variable buffer; but I really would like the ability to hover my mouse over some variable and see the value. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gud-tooltip-mode` is supposed to give you just that, I think.